# Как автоматически устанавливать файл .ipa без Xcode на физический девайс

Tags: ios, bash, test-automation, автоматизация, непрерывная-интеграция

Мы имеем `calabash+cucumber`, `fabrica` с веб приложением `beta` на девайсах, где мы можем посмотреть и установить последний из собранных билдов, ci - Bamboo, `ruby 2.0`, все тесты написаны на `ruby`.

Я могу написать скрипт который будет отправлять `ipa` файл сразу после сборки билда из Bamboo на мой тестовый сервер(где хранятся все тесты и запускаются с помощью calabash ios)

Далее мои мысли в следующем направлении:

1. Необходимо после получения `ipa` файла запустить скрипт, который автоматически устанавит `my.ipa` без `Xcode` на физический девайс
2. Затем я могу написать `bash` скрипт, который будет запускать авто-тесты на физических девайсах

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос, пожалуйста. «опросники мнений» не укладываются в тематику сайта: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Более менее конкретизировал вопрос.

Comment: увы, но это всё ещё «вопрос-опросник».

Comment: без xcode приходят в голову два варианта: через sync в itunes и через fabric/hockeyapp/testflight с принятием емейла на девайс и установкой. Оба варианта предполагают действия пользователя, так что полной автоматизации не получится. Можно попробовать один раз руками поставить билд через fabric, и потом он будет уже в приложении запрашивать разрешение на обновление, если видит новый билд, от этого можно мне кажется попробовать нарисовать автоматизацию

Comment: либо, подключить osx slave в bamboo и собирать на нем с подключенным девайсом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй XCode Server. Он должен уметь скачивать исходники, компилировать их и запускать на подключенных девайсах. Также у него есть АПИ для управления. Результат тестов можно будет посмотреть в браузере или получить по почте.

https://honzadvorsky.com/articles/2015-08-04-xcs_tutorials_1_getting_started/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/